# Laravel :: call method in helper class with constructor

Tags: laravel, constructor, controller, helper

as I mentioned in last question I am beginner in Laravel therefore I need some help ,I have to make helper class to create random Id for some tables ,I create this class with table constructor to recieve deffirent tables :

```
<?php
namespace App\Helpers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class RandomId
{
    public function __construct($my_table)
    {
        $this->my_table=$my_table;
    }

    public function get_id()
    {
        $id = mt_rand(1000000000, 9999999999); 
        if($this->check_id($id)){
            get_id();
        }
        return $id;
    }

    public function check_id($id)
    {
        $table=DB::table($this->my_table)->where('id',$id)->get();
        if (count($course)==0){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

then I add it as alias in config/app.php

```
'RandomId' => App\Helpers\RandomId::class,
```

now I want to call it in controller ,I did somethinf like this but don't work :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\course;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Helpers\RandomId;

class Course_controller extends Controller
{
    public function add(Request $request)
    {
       $id=RandomId::get_id('courses');
       dd($id);
    }
}
```

I get this error :`Non-static method App\Helpers\RandomId::get_id() should not be called statically`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `get_id` function is not static. You should add `static` keyword when defining static methods:

```
public static function get_id()
{
       ....
```

Comment: I get this error : `Using $this when not in object context`

Comment: you should also define `check_id` as static method and call it like this: `self::check_id($id)`

Comment: thanks alot I did all ,after I changed $this->mytable to self::$mytable I get this error : `Access to undeclared static property: App\Helpers\RandomId::$my_table`

Comment: yw! there are some problems with your code. First you defined constructor but never used it and also you use static functions so you won't need it anymore. Second when you define static methods it must not depend and also can't depend on not static properties like `$my_table`. I suggest you to take table name as a parameter of your static function. also don't forget to check as correct answer if it was helpful

Comment: Thanks alot , I remove the class and just use methods with paraneters